# PHPUnit + ZF : "Using $this when not in object context" while rendering view

Tags: php, zend-framework, view, phpunit

Problem: running phpunit causes next error:

```
PHPUnit_Framework_Exception: PHP Fatal error:  Using $this when not in object context in /path/to/index.phtml
```

Backtrace:

```
#0  include() called at [/path/to/Zend/View.php:108]
#1  Zend_View->_run(/path/to/index.phtml) called at [/path/to/Zend/View/Abstract.php:880]
#2  Zend_View_Abstract->render(index/index.phtml) called at [/path/to/Zend/Controller/Action/Helper/ViewRenderer.php:897]
#3  Zend_Controller_Action_Helper_ViewRenderer->renderScript(index/index.phtml, ) called at [/path/to/Zend/Controller/Action/Helper/ViewRenderer.php:918]
#4  Zend_Controller_Action_Helper_ViewRenderer->render() called at [/path/to/Zend/Controller/Action/Helper/ViewRenderer.php:957]
#5  Zend_Controller_Action_Helper_ViewRenderer->postDispatch() called at [/path/to/Zend/Controller/Action/HelperBroker.php:277]
#6  Zend_Controller_Action_HelperBroker->notifyPostDispatch() called at [/path/to/Zend/Controller/Action.php:523]
#7  Zend_Controller_Action->dispatch(indexAction) called at [/path/to/Zend/Controller/Dispatcher/Standard.php:295]
```

Can't understand what I'm missing, but as I see, `include` is calling from `Zend_View->run`, so `$this` must be visible in the view (and it works so without phpunit).

Can you tip me the direction to dig or some reasons of this behaviour?

Answer (score 0):

Can you please share with us the piece of code where you must have written -

```
/path/to/index.phtml
```

Just the lines of code around the above line and the filename. (config.module.php or something).

May be the above line of code (/path/to/) needs to be replaced with actual path.

Also if possible, can you share which tutorial or blog, you are using for the PHPUnit + ZF implementation.

Comment: About code: if you are using ZF, you know that calling 
    `/index/`
will rise 
    `Zend_View->run(/application/views/scripts/index/index.phtml)` 

(or any other extension you have set). So I can't understand what piece of code you need.


About PHPUnit + ZF: 
I am using only official PHPUnit docs and own knowledges of ZF (about 3 years of using). Built-in Zend_Test_PHPUnit unfortunatly is very out-of-date.